# run a .exe file with additional parameters

Tags: python

I am using windows and struggeling to get this work...

I can execute this in cmd.exe:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Test 123\Test.exe" "H:\Test Test\file.txt" -f "doStuff"
```

but when I try to do it in python:

```
subprocess.call([r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Test 123\Test.exe" "H:\Test Test\file.txt" -f "doStuff"'])
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing12.py", line 20, in <module>
    subprocess.call([r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Test 123\Test\Test.exe" "H:\Test Test\Folder\file.txt" -f "doStuff"'])
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

How can I execute it properly? Thanks.

Comment: I believe you need ```shell=True``` in the ```subprocess.call()```.  But be aware that this creates a potential security risk when using un-sanitized input

Comment: shell=True is the wrong answer. Passing this as a true list, rather than a single-entry one, is the right one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy holy crap I didn't even see that single quote. Good catch!!

Comment: @adsmith, I only took a quick look at it, not enough to actually make sure ```shell=True``` was the answer, it was just an initial guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to pass in an array, make it an actual array -- one argument per parameter, separated by commas. Otherwise you'll need to use `shell=True`, which has all the (generally undesirable) side effects of invoking a shell (and should just pass in your command string as a string, no array called for in that use case).

```
subprocess.call([
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test 123\Test.exe",
  "H:\Test Test\file.txt",
  "-f", "doStuff"])
```

If you don't use commas between your strings, they're consolidated together.

Comment: Thanks but that is not fully correct. `doStuff` needs to be `"doStuff"`. I tried to concatenate it with -f so I got `'-sf "doStuff"'` which is not working.

Comment: @Johnny: Have you tried the answer, or are you guessing that it is incorrect? The quotes in your `cmd.exe` example are interpreted by `cmd` itself and never reach `Test.exe`, while in the Python case you do not invoke `cmd.exe` at all.

Comment: @Johnny, I stand by my answer, for the reasons lanzz gave -- the **whole point** of passing in an array is to have your Python code do the argument-splitting ahead-of-time rather than needing to give the shell an argument string it can split itself. If you believe that this is incorrect, provide a test demonstrating it to be incorrect we can run ourselves without having these strictly hypothetical programs.